# Get a URL from a Django form and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, django-forms

I have a Django form and a Python function that counts words. So now when I input any text in the form, the program counts me the words.

My form is this one:

```
<html>

    <form method="POST" action="" id = "loginForm">
           {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="text" value= '{% if submitbutton == "Submit" %} {{ firstname }} {% endif %}'/>
        <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />

        {% if submitbutton == "Submit"  %}
        <h1 name = "resultado1"> texto introducido: {{ text }}</h1>
        <h1 name="resultado2"> tipo: {{ type }}</h1>
    {% endif %}

    </form>

</html>
```

Is there a way where I can get the text in the input, and use it somehow? For example: paste a URL in the form and click "submit" to get the data.
This is the `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from sample import text_examples

def vistaFormulario(request):
    text = request.POST.get('text')
    submitbutton = request.POST.get('Submit')
    m = str(text)
```

Neither `text`nor `m` have what I input in the form (an URL that I mentioned, for example).

Comment: Why are you making it so hard for people to help you? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It is question from a much bigger project and it is a little bit difficult for me to make it more simple to ask... I tried editing the question. Basicly, get whatever text of the form when clickinf submit@thebjorn

Comment: If you think it's difficult for you to make it "more simple to ask", then imagine how difficult it is to answer, without the bits and pieces you've skipped, and with all the extra cruft you've left in.. It's impossible for anyone to try to run this to figure out what the error is. At key points in your question your English is hard to decipher, which doesn't make it any easier to answer..

Comment: Both the `head` and `body` tags are missing in the HTML. It is a good idea to run it through an HTML validator, e.g. [the W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/), in this case after Django has processed it (the HTML can be captured from view source in the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in a different question right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702748/not-getting-the-value-of-a-form-in-django/50703125?noredirect=1#comment88416011_50703125).

Basically there had to be an

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

And add the rest of the method below to make it work:

```
if request.method=='POST':

   text = request.POST.get('text')
   submitbutton = request.POST.get('Submit')
   m = str(text)
   print(m)
   print(text)
```

Comment: Perhaps it could be more clear near *"And the rest of the code"*. I interpret it as having something to do with the `if`, but I don't find it clear. Perhaps rephrase?

Comment: I'll rephrase it! What I meant was "and the rest of the code of that answer". I guess I did not want to paste ALL the answer of another question, as I linked it! @PeterMortensen