# Not getting the value of a form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In Django I want to open a URL (this is posted by a user in a form) and after clicking the submit button (of the form) with the URL, get the data (the URL) and do some things with it (printing it in the view).

I only have one function in the `views.py` file, so I guess my main problem is that I should have two. But I am not really sure how to solve it, however have I tried.

My form is this one:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Practica Django
        </title>

    </head>

        <form method="POST" action="" id = "loginForm">
               {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="text" id= "text" value= '{% if submitbutton == "Submit" %} {{ firstname }} {% endif %}' maxlength="100"/>
            <input type="reset" name="Reset" id = "Reset" value="Reset" />
            <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id = "Submit" value="Submit" />

            {% if submitbutton == "Submit"  %}

            <h1 id = 4 name="resultado2"> {{ type }}</h1>
        {% endif %}

        </form>

</html>
```

In my views I have this:

```
def vistaFormulario(request,):
    text = request.POST.get('text')
    submitbutton = request.POST.get('Submit')
    m = str(text)
    print(m)
    print(text)

    # Descarga el contenido del HTML
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.elmundo.es/espana/2018/06/05/5b162c3b468aebd9678b4695.html') as response:
        page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    p = soup.find_all('p')
```

And so it continues. But I need to open that URL! But whichever the user has written in the form and push the input button!

As you can see, I have two `prints`, just to see what values do those values have. They have None before typing something and pressing the input button, and after pressing it, they have whatever you have written.

What I want is to get in this method whatever I input in the button *from the beginning*. I do not understand why they have none. I want to get the value, and then print them.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. They will of course will be `None` before you POST the form to the view. What's your use case for this?

Comment: Sorry, I will try to edit the question at the end for better explanation. But basicly, I want to open an url and get some data. So I need to open the url that someone inputs in the form. So in the beggining, I cannot open that url because the value is none. Would another method solve it?@BenjaminHicks

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, this makes more sense now.

Comment: The `body` tag is missing in the HTML. It is a good idea to run it through an HTML validator, e.g. [the W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/), in this case after Django has processed it (the HTML can be captured from view source in the browser).

Comment: I did not know about the validation service! I'll make sure to use it in future problems of this kind for sure @PeterMortensen Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your issue is that you do a call to Beautiful Soup, but you don't need to do it when the user initially loads the page and hasn't submitted the form.

The easiest solution is to put the logic that calls `bs` into an `if` block that only fires if you `POST`:

```
# Define these so that they have a value to be called in the template
text = submitbutton = ''
if request.method == 'POST':
    text = request.POST.get('text')
    submitbutton = request.POST.get('Submit')
    m = str(text)
    print(m)
    print(text)

    # Descarga el contenido del HTML
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.elmundo.es/espana/2018/06/05/5b162c3b468aebd9678b4695.html') as response:
       page = response.read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
   p = soup.find_all('p')

# This needs to be outside your 'if' clause, so that the page will render if the method isn't POST
context = {'text': text,
           'submitbutton': submitbutton,
           'type':q1}

return render(request, 'form/form.html', context)
```

From your sample, I'm not sure how `qt` gets defined or exactly why you're capturing the `submitbutton`, but this should work more or less.

Comment: It worked great! The only thing, the context and the return, there should be 2: one inside the if, and another one outside. But works perfectly fine! Thanks!

Comment: You could definitely have two returns. I usually try to make it so that my return and context work regardless of whether the form is empty or has a `POST`/`GET`. (If you look at the Django code samples, this tends to be a pattern). But glad it worked regardless!